# Why does a Java if statement fail when it ends in semicolon

Tags: java

I made a coding mistake while working on an application, it was a test for null reference. It took me hours to discover what the issue was, but what i don't understand is why the code behaved this way.

```
String name = null;
String value = null;

if(name != null && value != null);
{
    System.out.println("Values not null");
}
```

The if Statement ended with `;`, that was my mistake and the `Values not null` was printed even when it is obvious that both values are null. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This semicolon ends a statement (an empty one), so your code is translated by the compiler to something like this:

```
if(name != null && value != null)
{
  //nothing here
}
{
  System.out.println("Values not null");
}
```

In other words, if `if` expression is `true`, it executes empty block of code. Then no matter whether `if` was true or not, the runtime proceeds and runs the block containing `System.out`. Empty statement is still a statement, so the compiler accepts your code.

Another place where such a mistake can happen:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
{
  System.out.println("Y U always run once?");
}
```

or even worse (infinite loop):

```
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop);
{
  //...
  stop = true;
}
```

> It took me hours to discover what the issue was

Good IDE should immediately warn you about such statement as it's probably never correct (like `if(x = 7)` in some languages).

Comment: i used netbeans but it didn't warn me.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz.. An IDE will not warn you about this.. It is not considered as incorrect use of if..

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Eclipse warns you. It calls it `Dead Code`.

Comment: Well it seems that my Eclipse is cheating on me.. It doesn't warn me..

Comment: @RohitJain: turns out both IntelliJ and Eclipse **do** warn. I am not saying it's incorrect (it compiles), but it's suspicious and obscure.

Comment: In my (fairly old) version of Eclipse I get a warning "Empty control-flow statement", although I had to turn it on, i.e. Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Empty statement

Answer (score 5):

`;` terminates the statement.

```
if(name != null && value != null);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(name != null && value != null)
{
}
```

And the following code is simply a block of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(name != null && value != null);
{
    System.out.println("Values not null");
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(name != null && value != null){}

{
    System.out.println("Values not null");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(name != null && value != null);
```

Here your if statement got finished due to semi-colon...

So, it is just like an `empty` if block: -

```
if(name != null && value != null) {}
```

So your next code becomes an **Initializer block**: -

```
{
    System.out.println("Values not null");
}
```

Since it is an **initializer block**.. It will be executed always no matter what your `if` condition evaluated to..

Answer (score 1):

It's the standard grammar rules.  Semicolons terminate statements, but statements may be empty, so these lines:

```
if (...);
{
}
```

are equivalent to:

```
if (...) /* do nothing */ ;

{
    ...
}
```

The following `{ ... }` statement just looks like any other code block, and will always be executed, because the `if` statement is done with by then.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if(name != null && value != null) {
   // empty code block
}

System.out.println("Values not null");
```

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon ends the statement, and thus detaches the if from the following block.

Note that blocks can be arbitrary.

```
{
System.out.println("This is some code");
}
```

`if(true);` This is valid, and it does nothing. The language allowing this is pretty stupid, although IDEs should catch these issue with warnings and the like.

Answer (score 0):

One bare `;` is a whole empty statement. After the if there has to be exactly one statement that will be executed when `if` is true. The one statement that is executed in your case is the empty statement. You can combine more statements to one with `{statement; statement;...}`

Answer (score 0):

Understand that conditional statements needn't always follow with opening and closing braces. Most languages will allow you to simply emit the braces if you only want to execute a single statement when the terms of the condition are met.

Meaning that the following is completely valid, for instance:

```
if (var1 == true && var2 == true) var3 = 'both true';
{
    //block here, this is always executed regardless of the statements outcome
}
```

Essentially, your code does exactly this. Except your single statement is determined to be  `;` (yes, this is considered a statement).

What you wrote is the same as:

```
if(name != null && value != null) {
    // do nothing
}

System.out.println("Values not null");
```