# Trouble comparing string's in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

Why does this return true?

```
String b =  "(5, 5)";
String a =  "(7, 8)" ;
if(a.equals(b));
{

    System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```

Output:

```
Somehow "(7, 8)" and "(5, 5)" are the same
```

Comment: [Why do java if statement fail when it ends in semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772221/why-do-java-if-statement-fail-when-it-ends-in-semicolon)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if(a.equals(b)) { }
{
   System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```

So the print statement in a block that'll be *always* executed regardless of the condition, since the body of the `if` doesn't include that statement.

See the [JLS - 14.6. The Empty Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6):

> An empty statement **does nothing**.
>
> EmptyStatement:
>
> ```
> ;
> ```
>
> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally

Comment: Ahh.. language specification.

Comment: I was about to post this link!! Edit: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112532/1673391

Comment: Fast and furious......

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's an useful link.

Comment: He went to future in time and stole my link.

Answer (score 4):

You have `;` after your if statement.

use:

```
if(a.equals(b)) {
    System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112532/1651233).

Comment: It might be helpful to also explain what happens when you put the semi-colon there.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a.equals(b));<-----
```

You have an extre ; there and statements ends there.

That's like writing

```
if(a.equals(b));
```

and a block here

```
{

    System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```

So get rid of that extra `;`

Comment: *a static block here* - It is not a static block, AFAIK.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ So what you think of it ?? Can you please correct me ?

Comment: It is an [anonymous block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1563030/2024761). This is a static block - `static { ... }`.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ I usually refer them static's :). There is a good reason to change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition satisfied, but nothing will execute since `;` in following.

```
if(a.equals(b)); // ;  this is equal to if(a.equals(b)){}
```

Correct this as follows

```
if(a.equals(b)){
 System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you typed a `;` after the `if` statement. Then it will be evaluated as `if(a.equals(b)){};`, which means do nothing.

```
String b =  "(5, 5)";
String a =  "(7, 8)" ;
if(a.equals(b)); <-- remove this ';'
{
    System.out.printf("Somehow \"%s\" and \"%s\" are the same" ,a,b);
}
```